# Django route giving 404

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-yasg

I've got a **route** registered in the **urls.py** file of my django main app as:

```
router.register(r"visual/(?P<random_url>[\w]+)/$", views.LinkTest, basename="test")
```

and the **url patterns** defineded as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Admin
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    # Model API Routes
    path("rest/api/latest/", include(router.urls))
]
```

which means I should be able to hit the **viewset** via the following call

http://localhost:8000/rest/api/latest/visual/random_string/

but I'm getting a **404**

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catch here is although your url `visual/random_string/` is matching with regex `visual/(?P<random_url>[\w]+)/$`, router adds `/$` automatically to your specified regex.

Hence, internally, your regex is getting converted to `visual/(?P<random_url>[\w]+)/$/$` which is not matching with `visual/random_string/`.

So, remove `/$` from your regex and just keep the follwing code.

```
router.register(r"visual/(?P<random_url>[\w]+)", views.LinkTest, basename="test")
```

Comment: Yes you were right it worked for me Thank you Mohit